# Where does the address of a dynamic symbol come from

Tags: c, elf

I am writing a userland elf loader as a side project to learn more about ELF Files and how they work. I am wondering where to get the address to load a symbol from a dynamic library(`libc.so.6`).
When I disassemble the program I get:

```
$objdump -d test | grep puts
  400420:       ff 25 f2 0b 20 00       jmpq   *0x200bf2(%rip)        # 601018 <puts@GLIBC_2.2.5>
```

`0x200bf2` is the address where the function goes, but where do I get it from?

EDIT:I am asking for where it is loaded not where it is defined, so `st_value` is irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse the elf manually.

This kind of information can be found in a **Symbol Table** section:

> This contains a list of all of the symbols (program entry points, addresses of variables, etc.) that are defined or referenced within the file, the address associated with the symbol, and some kind of tag indicating the type of the symbol.
>
> (*From [The Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1059)*)

To find the symbol table, iterate over the sections until you find a section for which `sh_type = SHT_SYMTAB`, then parse it appropriately.

The symbol table is an array of `Elf32_Sym` and/or `Elf64_Sym` structs. The address of the method will be assigned to `st_value` member of the struct, which is relative to the section header at index `st_shndx`.

For more information, you can refer to:

- [ELF format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#Program_header)
- [Symbol table format](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-0690/chapter6-79797.html)
- The source code of the [readelf](https://chromium.googlesource.com/native_client/nacl-binutils/+/upstream/master/binutils/readelf.c)

Comment: Which entry on the symbol table contains the address?

Comment: @ZachS, the symbol table is an array of `Elf32_Sym` and/or `Elf64_Sym` structs. The address of the method will be assigned to `st_value` member of the struct. Added a link to the symbol table format as a reference.

Comment: It is undefined in the file as it is a dynamic symbol, I have the st_value for where it is defined(in libc.so.6) I am wondering how to get address where it will be loaded.  st_value for dynamic/undefined symbols is zero which is incorrect

Comment: In my program the st_shndx of puts and __libc_start_main are the same(13) and both values are zero, could that be correct?

Comment: thank you I was using the wrong shndx the whole time(I was using the one in the library file not the one in the loaded file), I probably couldn't have seen that with out your post

Comment: @ZachS, glad I could help!